# What are the consistency guarantees of the Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

I've written a test suite for my google drive api library and am witnessing some non-deterministic behavior. In the simplest case, I can insert a permission on a file, then immediately get a list of permissions on the file and I don't see the newly inserted permission.

I'm chalking this up to eventual consistency being eventual, but it would be nice to know if this is actually the case; the documentation makes no mention of consistency delays.

Comment: Are you setting the permissions to a file or to a folder ?  After setting the permissions to a folder, i've seen it takes time to propagate to the files inside that folder.

Comment: I can replicate this scenario on folders and files. I have **another** non-deterministic scenario, actually: if I create a file in a folder, then change the permissions on the folder, the file sometimes, but not always, receives the permission change.

Comment: im also seeing this behaviour. would be good to know if there is any documentation or "hard refresh" workaround

Comment: I can successfully add a permission via the api, but then can't see the permission via the UI. Other users DO see the permission in the UI. _some_ shared folders dont show up when searched for, some do

Answer (score 3):

I can't see this documented anywhere but there is a simple experiment you can do.

Adding and removing permissions is an asynchronous and queued task in my opinion and eventual consistency is my observation too. You can confirm this with a GSuite for Business account by conducting a test as follows:

1. In the Drive UI, upload a folder tree structure with a root folder, 3 or 4 levels of sub-folders and 300 to 500 files. You may get away with fewer but this is how many I used.
2. In the Drive UI, share the root of those folders with another user on your domain.
3. In Admin Console > Reports > Audit > Drive, add Filters as follows:

   - Event name: User Sharing Permissions Change
   - User name: the email of the user you added in step 2.
   - Owner: your email
   - Date and time range:

     - From: add yesterday's date
     - To: add today's date and 23:59 as time
4. Press search. You should see hundreds of events - one for every file and folder you added in step 1. Each event shows the exact time stamp of the permission being added.

As you should see, the permissions are not added instantly. It can take many minutes/hours depending on the numbers involved and (I assume) indeterminate work going on in the Google cloud.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed. If you think about Google's infrastructure, it's all about read performance and data integrity through massive distribution. The inevitable consequence of that is that write performance is relatively poor and asynchronous.